# Is it possible to add an image in the top left corner of a div's border while cutting off the border?

Tags: html, css

I have this image I am trying to replicate: 
[image: Quote with border and image in corner]

Basically, I want the border to go around the image and cut off within a certain distance.

I cannot seem to get the border to cut off.

This is the HTML for this quote and image

```
<div class="quote-container">
  <img class="testimonial-img" src="./Photos/StethoscopeVector.png" alt="">
  <div class="quote-container-text">
    <h3>Testimonial Quote</h3>
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean mollis<br/>erat vel ultricies imperdiet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br/>
        adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit."
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS for Quote and Image

```
.quote-container {
    padding: 5em 0;
    height: 100%
}

.testimonial-img {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 11.5em;
    margin-top: -3em;
}

.quote-container-text {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 2em;
    border: 2px solid white;
    width: 65%;
    padding: 2em;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Which currently looks like this image: 
[image: Quote with image and border Issue]

I have tried using shape-outside but it doesn't work and I believe it's because the image is being set to absolute.

This is the [stethoscope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nj8on.png) image. White image, no background.

Comment: Your example image has a solid background, so its easy to have the image have that same background color and overlay the border. But your attempt has a transparent background on top of an image background which makes things much more difficult

Comment: Put the image in a `div` and set the background of the `div` to the same image/color as the body.

Comment: maybe you could use the css property `border-image` and use a gradient that goes from transparent to white for the top and left borders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all move your image inside of your container-text  and then give border to the right and bottom of it and use pseudo selectors :after and :before for the left border and top border.

for more explanation please refer this snippet.

```css
.quote-container {
  padding: 5em 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.testimonial-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: -13px;
}
.quote-container-text {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 2em;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  width: 65%;
  padding: 2em;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.quote-container-text:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
  background-color: #fff;
}
.quote-container-text:after {
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  content: "";
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color: #2196F3">
  <div class="quote-container">
    <div class="quote-container-text">
      <img class="testimonial-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nj8on.png" alt="">
      <h3>Testimonial Quote</h3>
      <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean mollis<br/>erat vel ultricies imperdiet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br/>
        adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit."
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

for background-image instead of bg-color.

```css
.quote-container {
  padding: 5em 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/vintage-retro-grungy-background-design-and-pattern-texture-picture-id656453072?k=6&m=656453072&s=612x612&w=0&h=4TW6UwMWJrHwF4SiNBwCZfZNJ1jVvkwgz3agbGBihyE=');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.testimonial-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: -13px;
}
.quote-container-text {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 2em;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  width: 65%;
  padding: 2em;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.quote-container-text:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
  background-color: #fff;
}
.quote-container-text:after {
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  content: "";
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="quote-container">
    <div class="quote-container-text">
      <img class="testimonial-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nj8on.png" alt="">
      <h3>Testimonial Quote</h3>
      <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean mollis<br/>erat vel ultricies imperdiet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br/>
        adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit."
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Thank You...

Comment: this will works perfect for every screen if you have any doubts you can ask me.

Comment: The OP's _"Which currently looks like this image:"_ image looks like it doesn't use a solid background color, but an image for a background can you make it work with that?

Comment: ya sure why not.

Comment: yes that seems to work well, I just wanted to see it in a snippet

Comment: yes you can check the second snippet i have use bg-image for your main container and it will work perfectly.

Comment: This worked out perfectly. Thank you! Pseudo elements seem to be powerful little things that I need to experiment with more. I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your image has a transparent background, and it appears above the border. To fix that, you can set the border on an absolutely positioned pseudo-element (`::before`), and use `clip-path` to remove the top left corner:

```css
.quote-container {
  padding: 5em;
  background: steelblue;
}

.quote-container-text {
  position: relative;
  width: 65%;
  padding: 2em;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: white; 
}

.quote-container-text::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 2px solid white;
  clip-path: polygon(55px 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 55px, 55px 55px);
  content: '';
}

.testimonial-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote-container">
  <div class="quote-container-text">
    <img class="testimonial-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nj8on.png" alt="">
    <h3>Testimonial Quote</h3>
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean mollis<br/>erat vel ultricies imperdiet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br/> adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit."
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this would be to use an image with a background color the same as the background color of the outermost container. Also, it's important to realize that setting something to `absolute` will make it absolute to the innermost container that has a `relative` positioning. Note that I used some random image from the web for the example, but you can conform it to your image. **If you want your transparent image to have a background, wrap it in a div and set the background of the div.**

First move the image inside the quote container text.

```
<div class="quote-container">
  <div class="quote-container-text">

  <div id="test-img-container">
    <img class="testimonial-img" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/medical-174/100/healthy-06-512.png" alt="">
  </div>
    <h3>Testimonial Quote</h3>
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean mollis<br/>erat vel ultricies imperdiet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br>
        adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit."
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Next set the image to absolute with `top` and `left` stylings and make the `quote-container-text` element to be relatively positioned:

```
.quote-container {
    padding: 5em 0;
    height: 100%;
    background:steelblue;
}

#test-img-container{
  position: absolute;
    left:-25px;
    top:-25px;
    background:steelblue;
}

.testimonial-img {
    width:50px;
    height:auto;
}

.quote-container-text {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 2em;
    border: 2px solid white;
    width: 65%;
    padding: 2em;
    position:relative;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Also note that this works best if you specify a hard width to the image so that you can evenly use the margin stylings on the image.

https://jsfiddle.net/dgf1ms8r/7/

[image]